# git prevent auto merge when changing branches

Tags: git, merge

I have my master branch.  I want to make some changes locally to test some ideas out so I create a new branch:

```
git checkout -b new_branch
```

I do some work on that branch.  By boss calls and I need to make a fix on the master branch.  So I switch back to master:

```
git checkout master
```

But that then merges any changes that I made in new_branch into master,  which I absolutely do not want.  I want to be able to switch branches without automatic merging until I have completed my testing in new_branch.

How do I do that?

Comment: git checkout only does a merge if you pass `--merge`.

Comment: Stash your changes first.

Comment: I don't think you actually mean merge.

Use `git stash` on your feature branch, switch to master, do what you need to and then when back on your feature branch use `git stash apply` to put your uncommited changes back.

Comment: Josh Lee is correct, these changes aren't *merged* in a technical sense, they're simply *carried over* if possible (in the work-tree, and the index if you have `git add`-ed them). As in the other comments you can use `git stash` to commit the changes, in commits that are on *no* branch. But I recommend using `git worktree` instead, as long your Git version is at least 2.6.

Comment: Yes,  they are not "merged" until I add, commit and push.  But the point is I need to be able to change over to my master branch and work on it without having to worry about accidentally committing code that I was working on the other branch. I will try the stash.

Comment: `git stash` or just commit to your `new_branch`... Creating perhaps temporary commits is why you create `new_branch` in the first place. Whether these commits will be merged to `master` as-is or re-written on rebase is a different story---the kind of flexibility that we all expect from a tool like a DVCS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before you switch branches, put your local changes aside with `git stash save "Meaningful message for what goes here"`. Once back on the branch, run `git stash pop`.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you don't commit your last changes and move to another branch.

First you need to commit the last changes with:

```
git add .

git commit -m "your message"
```

Then you can move to another branch with:

```
git checkout otherBranch
```